# Extracting text from inside a circular border

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to develop a script using Python and OpenCV to detect some highlighted regions on a scanned instrumentation diagram and output text using Tesseract's OCR function. My workflow is first to detect the general vicinity of the region of interest, and then apply processing steps to remove everything aside from the blocks of text (lines, borders, noise). The processed image is then feed into Tesseract's OCR engine.

This workflow is works on about half of the images, but fails on the rest due to the text touching the borders. I'll show some examples of what I mean below:

Step 1: Find regions of interest by creating a mask using InRange with the color range of the highlighter.

Step 2: Contour regions of interest, crop and save to file.

--- Referenced code begins here ---

Step 3:  Threshold image and apply Canny Edge Detection

Step 4: Contour the edges and filter them into circular shape using cv2.approxPolyDP and looking at ones with vertices greater than 8. Taking the first or second largest contour usually corresponds to the inner edge.

Step 5: Using masks and bitwise operations, everything inside contour is transferred to a white background image. Dilation and erosion is applied to de-noise the image and create the final image that gets fed into the OCR engine.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import pytesseract 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'

d_path = "Test images\\"

img_name = "cropped_12.jpg"

img = cv2.imread(d_path + img_name)  # Reads the image

## Resize image before calculating contour 
height, width = img.shape[:2]
img = cv2.resize(img,(2*width,2*height),interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)  

img_orig = img.copy()           # Makes copy of original image  

img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    # Convert to grayscale

#  Apply threshold to get binary image and write to file
_, img = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)


# Edge detection 
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)

# Find contours of mask threshold 
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Find contours associated w/ polygons with 8 sides or more 
cnt_list = []
area_list = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
for j in contours:
    poly_pts = cv2.approxPolyDP(j,0.01*cv2.arcLength(j,True),True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(j)
    if (len(poly_pts) > 8) & (area == max(area_list)):
        cnt_list.append(j)

cv2.drawContours(img_orig, cnt_list, -1, (255,0,0), 2)

# Show contours 
cv2.namedWindow('Show',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Show",img_orig)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Zero pixels outside circle 
mask = np.zeros(img.shape).astype(img.dtype)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, cnt_list, (255,255,255))
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

a = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)
wh_back = np.ones(img.shape).astype(img.dtype)*255
b = cv2.bitwise_and(wh_back,wh_back,mask = mask_inv)

res = cv2.add(a,b)

# Get rid of noise 
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
res = cv2.dilate(res, kernel, iterations=1)
res = cv2.erode(res, kernel, iterations=1)

# Show final image 
cv2.namedWindow('result',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("result",res)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When code works, these are the images that get outputted: 
[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOZbs.jpg)

However, in the instances where the text touches the circular border, the code assumes part of the text is part of the larger contour and ignores the last letter. For example: 
[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9tig.jpg)

Are there any processing steps that can help me bypass this problem? Or perhaps a different approach? I've tried using Hough Circle Transforms to try to detect the borders, but they're quite finicky and doesn't work as well as contouring.

I'm quite new to OpenCV and Python so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be great to let us know what worked for you in your specific use case. In entire SO you are the only one who has posted on the same use case as mine. Your own solution is very helpful and I tried it for my [example drawing](https://imgur.com/a/nzWajdF) but not very successful. Can you share your insights for a) how can text be read inside circles, squares, squares inside diamonds, rectangular equipment, etc? I am trying to remove all shapes to to OCR on text but needs help. b) Is there a way to make the black thick pipeline completely extract OR remove with all symbols on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Hough circle transform didn't work for you I think you're best option will be to approximate the boarder shape. The best method I know for that is: Douglas-Peucker algorithm which will make your contour simpler by reducing the perimeter on pics.

You can check this reference file from OpenCV to see the type of post processing you can apply to your boarder. They also mention Douglas-Peucker:
[OpenCV boarder processing](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

Comment: Playing around with the parameters of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm would result in either the original result or no result outputted. However, I found that the easiest way of approximating the border shape was to use the cv2.minEnclosingCircle() function on the contour.

Comment: Good to know, did you figure out why the Douglas-Peucker is limited in this use case ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch. After OTSU thresholding. Erode and dilate the image. This will result in vanishing of very thin joints. The code for the same is below.

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
th3 = cv2.erode(th3, kernel,iterations=1)
th3 = cv2.dilate(th3, kernel,iterations=1)
```

Let me know how it goes. I have couple more idea if this did not work.

Comment: So far none of the morphological operations have worked on this particular image. The joint that connects the B to the circle is comparatively thicker than the letters. Even simply eroding the image breaks up the letters before the joint itself.

Comment: @harshkn If I follow your advice what chance this [example image](https://imgur.com/a/nzWajdF) has all its connections vanished? a) Is there any way to make disappear all the shapes so that all the text is unbounded to perform OCR? b) Is there any way to completely remove the black thick line or may be extract it with all symbols on it?

Comment: @SKR I don't think you can remove just lines and NOT text using erode and dilate. The thing that comes to my mind if MSER. Check [this](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/mser.html), it might help you.

Comment: @harshkn Thanks for the MSER link however I was thinking of a simpler approach to recognize the text bounded in different shapes. Approach 1: use Hough circle to detect circles and mask them using their center and radius so text is free. Approach 2: find all contours and filter them with maximum area since characters will constitute the smallest contours. Now there are so many contours generated after Canny edge detection that I am not able to reduce them to a thin single line. That's why I was thinking to erode them to minimal to have less contours. Can you suggest something?